# using action handler to Fetch Record from OBProvider.getInstance().get(class)

Tags: java, data-access-layer, openbravo

Want u fetch all record from a table which name is shipment type

```
ShipmentType st = OBProvider.getInstance().get(ShipmentType.class);
```

what should i use to know the lenght of it to run a for loop

Example:

```
for(i=0;i<=st.getID.length();i++;) {
 ToDo my action 
}
```

PS:Using Openbravo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to fetch records from Openbravo's DAL.

- OBCriteria
- OBQuery
- Using SQL/HQL Query Interface.

check the documentation of **`OBQuery`** [here](https://code.openbravo.com/docs/erp/devel/pi/org/openbravo/dal/service/OBQuery.html).

Check the implementation of **`OBCriteria`** in [`Openbravo's wiki`](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_develop_a_DAL_background_process) page.